# 3d printing - How to push out internal face so as to reduce infill material

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I am attempting to print a head sculpture but discovered that there is too much "wall thickness" which would result in needless internal infill during 3d printing.
I have been using various brushes trying to "push out" the internal wall so as to reduce the wall thickness in behind the mouth/nose etc.
The highlighted red line indicates the hollowed out portion.

Any tips?

[image]

Comment: Just an idea... Duplicate the mesh, make the duplicate unselectable, give it a different color, maybe make it semi-transparent. Now edit the original mesh, hide the outer shell to only modify the inner vertices. If you didn't make the duplicate semi-transparent, you can turn the X-ray mode on. Now you can use proportional editing mode or sculpting to bring the vertices close to the outer shell and you have a visual cue when they intersect. Perhaps you also want to use solidify modifier to get some margin (min thickness) as well...

Comment: sounds promising! I will investigate. Thanks!